# How to fix a chipped door frame

Tags: repair, doors, frame

I knocked a small cabinet over after waking up in the middle of the night and it fell and hit my door frame, chipping it. As this is a rental I need to fix it, although I have very little diy experience so an easy method would be great [image: the door frame]

Answer (score 1):

OK, get a sanding block and sand that area smooth. Concentrate on the ridges and smooth them out. Then get some vinyl spackle and fill in the grooves. You could also use joint compound if you have some handy.Smooth it out and try to match the paint and paint the section. The landlord might even have touch up paint.